# Search in External content type

Tags: 2010, search, external-content-type

I am new to SharePoint. I am trying to add a search box to a list but I can't figure out how to do it. I have added an external content type and want to be able to search in it.

So what I did was adding the WebPart: Search Box. But **how to I tell the search box where to search?** I thought maybe I had to set the connection but the connection menu is grayed out and telling:

> "*The WebPart you are connecting from does not allow authoring of
>   connections.*"

I am using SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can use just the search webpart to query external content types.

Assuming you have the content type correctly configured using BCS then you can set up a simple search site to test using the Basic Search Center template.

In essence you use SharePoint Designer 2010 to define the external content type and set up a SharePoint Server search crawl that includes that external data.

You will need to configure a Read List and Read Item operation for the external content type.

Reference and steps [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg512148.aspx#confsps_part1_addlresource).

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you are describing.  I would create a custom search scope.  Launch a full crawl.  Then configure your search box WebPart to use the custom scope.